# Why video.requestPictureInPicture() works only once?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video, picture-in-picture

I'm trying enter and exit PIP mode of video via Javascript onscroll function and I can only once enter and exit this mode.
Here's my codepen:

```js
    if (!myVideo.paused && myVideo.currentTime > 0 
        && !myVideo.ended && !isVideoPIP) {
      console.log('runPip')
      myVideo.requestPictureInPicture()
        .then(()=>{isVideoPIP = true;})
        .catch(e=>console.log(e.message))
    }
```

https://codepen.io/Greggg/pen/WBdeJG

Second time I have this error message "Must be handling a user gesture if there isn't already an element in Picture-in-Picture."

Comment: Any updates or workaround on this?

Answer (score 4):

If it doesn't work, it's because `scroll` is not part of the [user-trusted events](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation).

Now, that sometimes it works is actually weird... but has a rational explanation.

User trusted events are usually considered alive for quite some time, but they should die eventually:

```js
btn_500ms.onclick = e => trigger_in(500); // works
btn_6s.onclick = e => trigger_in(6000); // fails

function trigger_in(ms) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    video.requestPictureInPicture()
      .then(() => {
        // auto-exit in 1s
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.exitPictureInPicture();
        }, 1000);
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }, ms);
};
```

```html
<video id="video" controls="" muted loop autoplay src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm"></video>
<button id="btn_500ms">trigger PiP in 500ms</button>
<button id="btn_6s">trigger PiP in 6s</button>
```

So I guess that what you interpreted as being working only on first scroll was actually caused by some circumstances where you did scroll after less than the max-life-time of a user trusted event (seems to be 5s in current Chrome74 btw). You can try by simply clicking anywhere in your codepen page before scrolling again.

Comment: I can confirm this. Triggering picture-in-picture mode works only if the user interacts with the player first. For example, because they hit "play". If you have autoplay on, for example, and you try to switch to pip, it fails because the user never interacted with the player. Additionally, exiting pip resets the interaction, so the second time around, triggering pip fails.

Comment: In my experience with Chrome on Windows, it works if the user has interacted with the page. This also aligns with their autoplay policy linked [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#new-behaviors)